# jQuery mega menu display only the clicked parent submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple Mega Menu. I am trying to display the sub menu of the parent menu item clicked. But for some reason when I click the parent item all the sub menu's are displaying instead of the clicked parent item sub menu. What I am doing wrong.

Here is my JSFiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/jokcLjkb/4/

here is my js code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.drop").on('click', function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.mainNav li > .drop-full-col").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

Thanks and Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
$("ul.mainNav li > .drop-full-col")
```

Will select all the submenus because you target the main nav and all the `<div class="drop-full-col">` elements. You need to select only the ones relative to the link you click on, and to do that you need to use `this` to refer to the link being clicked on. So change:

```
$("ul.mainNav li > .drop-full-col").css("display","block");
```

to

```
$(this).closest('li').find(".drop-full-col").css("display", "block");
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yce9b4n2/)**

`.closest('li')` will look for the closest list item when you click the link, and `.find(".drop-full-col")` will then search down the DOM for the div you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying but when I test your JSFiddle, the sub-menu of other parent items are still visible. For example click on house flags and then click on windsocks. you will see house flags sub-menu is still being shown under the windsocks sub-menu

Comment: I just corrected your code, I didn't add the ability to hide items. For that you could do something like add `$(".drop-full-col").hide()` https://jsfiddle.net/yce9b4n2/1/